# HTML text input, using JS regex to only allow certain characters to be typed

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm not overly familiar with Regex and am just beginning with Javascript.

I'm trying to make it so when the user types in the textarea they are forced to follow a certain pattern. The pattern is 'X' followed by 9 numbers. If first character is any letter other than 'X' then it won't type, and after they do type 'X' if it is any character other than a number then it won't type, or if it's a series of numbers longer than 9 digits long then it will also not type.

Right now with the code I've got it will look for a letter for the first character, although not specifically an 'X', and kind of does the opposite in that it waits until this pattern is met and then replaces the text with nothing.

`<textarea id="scan-data" onkeypress="if(this.value.match(/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{9,9}$/gm)) this.value=this.value.replace(/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{9,9}$/gm,'')" onkeyup="if(this.value.match(/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{9,9}$/gm)) this.value=this.value.replace(/^[A-Za-z][0-9]{9,9}$/gm,'')"></textarea><br>`

The only text allowed in the textarea should be X and then 9 digits, anything else should automatically be replaced with "" (ie. nothing)

Would appreciate any help anyone can offer!
Thanks

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]\d{0,9}$/`  and you should be good to go. It's all about your code sitting between the character reader device and the print to screen device. When you're ready to check submit, use `/^[a-zA-Z]\d{9}$/` to verify.

Comment: I guess for a replacement, use `/^([a-zA-Z]\d{0,9})?.*$/` and replace with capture group 1.

Comment: I'm trying to make this work in real-time rather than when you hit submit, so if the first character you type isn't an X then it will immediately remove what you've written. The same logic following the X with 9 numbers.

Comment: You don't  seem to understand the regex I've given you `/^([a-zA-Z]\d{0,9})?.*$/` . It literally is to remove unwanted on a character basis.  Handle a typed character from the input, run the regex replacement,  repeat. https://regex101.com/r/yrstoX/1

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/hkp4m6y9/2/, isn't it what you asked for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's it! Although it works the same way by just using onkeyup and removing onkeypress, so I'm wondering if I can just use onkeyup on it's own. If I wanted to have it insert a new line (\n) when X and 9 digits were typed, would the best way to do this be using match and inserting a new line when the match is true?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you want to only allow a single `X123456789` value in the text area, or on every line?

Comment: Every line, so once X123456789 is detected, it automatically goes on to a new line where the user is again restricted to the same pattern of input format

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://jsfiddle.net/jhqygLvp/ so it is now going on to a new line, but it is not applying the regex to any values on the new line. EDIT: the only way I could think to resolve this would be to split every line and loop through them ensuring they all match the regex, but I wondered if there was a way to avoid splitting and looping

Comment: Please check Ryszard's update, probably, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x.value.replace(/^(X\d{0,9})?.*$\n?/gm, (x,y) => y !== undefined ? y + (y.length==10 ? '\n' : '') : '');
```

See [how the expression works](https://regex101.com/r/S93qRU/1).

**JavaScript code**:

```js
function myFunction(x){
  x.value = x.value.replace(/^(X\d{0,9})?.*$\n?/gm, (x,y) => y !== undefined ? y + (y.length==10 ? '\n' : '') : '');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="scan-data" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"></textarea><br>
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to $1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    X                        'X'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{0,9}                  digits (0-9) (between 0 and 9 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of $1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in $1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        the end of the line
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n?                      an optional LF (line  feed) symbol
```